# MongoDB and missing index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, replicaset

after migrating replica set to standalone I have some weird issues with the resulting MongoDB setup. For example, an index on a collection is missing. But trying to `reIndex()` the collection fails as well with this error message:

```
> db.members.reIndex()
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: dictionary myapp.members.$channel_id_1 should exist, but we got ENOENT",
    "code" : 16988,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

The question is how to reindex a collection that misses its index :)

Many thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: This is an interesting problem, it might be good to find out how you caused this inconsistency, anyway can't you just run ensureInde() to remake that inde?

Comment: You tried to db.collection.reIndex() ?
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/reIndex/

Comment: @Barno: yes, exactly what I did, see my post above :)

Comment: sorry! today I'm slow :).. I need a Coffee

Comment: @Sammaye: ensureIndex() returns me the same error message. The question is: would it help to remove all local.* data files and restart the MongoDB? All the metadata will be recreated automatically, right?

Comment: Yeah, though it is a harsh way but that might be the only way :( I really know of no better way

Comment: Can you show us the output of `db.members.getIndexes()`? Have you tried dropping the index and then re-ensuring it? I'm curious to know how you did the migration to standalone as well.

Comment: have you tried running db.repairdatabase()?

Comment: Looks like your migration failed, despite the fact that you did not notice any errors. If you still have your replica set, I would first verify that it is healthy and then run the migration again. If you don't have the replica set anymore, then I would try deleting the collection and restoring it from backup.

Comment: Looks like an unclean / inconsistent file copy. As others have said, go back to some sort of good working copy. Since you migrated to a standalone, we will assume you don't really care about your data. :-)

Comment: do you have list on indexes on members collection before migration? Did you take any backup before converting replica set to standalone?